# Fetch JSON values from another file in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON file like below.

**defult.json**

```
const serviceToUSe = [
    {
        "service": {
            "wordpress": {
                "price": 1,
                "image": "wordpress",
                "desc": "A simple wordpress template for you to start blogging / webpage now",
            }
        }
    }
];

export default serviceToUSe;
```

This file is located at `public/service`.

I would like to import above file to `CreateService.js` file located at `src/` folder.

**CreateService.js**

```
import { serviceToUSe } from '../public/service/default.json';

class CreateService extends React.Component {

  ShowProvider(props) {
    var out;
    Object.keys(this.serviceToUSe.value).map((obj, i) => {
      out = <option>{this.serviceToUSe.value[obj]}</option>;
    }
    return out
  };
}
```

Comment: You can't put that into a `.json` file. Change the filename to `default.js` and change the export statement to `export {serviceToUSe}`. Will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing JavaScript in JSON file. You can't actually declare variables in JSON.

We generally use `json-loader` module to import JSON in react. If you have used CRA then it'll already be there.

Correct JSON :

```
[
    {
        "service": {
            "wordpress": {
                "price": 1,
                "image": "wordpress",
                "desc": "A simple wordpress template for you to start blogging / webpage now"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Things to note :

1. No trailing commas
2. No semicolons at end of literal
3. No export statements

Now you can import it like this from JS files :

```
import serviceToUSe  from '../public/service/default.json';
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike @Omkar76 in his very nice answer, I'm going to assume you actually want to end up with a javascript array rather than with a JSON text in your `CreateService.js` file. I'm making that assumption based on what you do with the `serviceToUSe` variable after you import it from `default.json`. So here is how to make your code work.

1. Change the file name from `default.json` to `default.js` because you're writing JS code on it.
2. Change the export statement to `export {serviceToUSe}`. So your `default.js` looks like this:

```
const serviceToUSe = [
    {
        "service": {
            "wordpress": {
                "price": 1,
                "image": "wordpress",
                "desc": "A simple wordpress template for you to start blogging / webpage now",
            }
        }
    }
];

export {serviceToUSe};
```

And this should do it.

Comment: In my solution OP won't end up with a string. Actually `json-loader` module handles the parsing of json. In my solution `serviceToUSe` will be a javascript array and not merely a string. I hope OP @abu will take note of this. Thanks :)